# Bootstrap Checkboxes with Input Field

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a question, maybe "Which colors do you like best?" and I have checkboxes that the user can select:

```html
What is your favorite color?
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="id1">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="id1">Red</label>
</div>
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="id2">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="id2">Green</label>
</div>
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="id3">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="id3">Blue</label>
</div>
ADD "OTHER" INPUT HERE
```

How can I add an input field next to one of them to add an "Other" option? Thanks!!

Comment: Each of your inputs is missing a `>` on a separate note.

Comment: @GetSet fixing now. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you simply add a custom input text element below the checkboxes?

Comment: So you want a checkbox to the left of a text input?

Comment: @GetSet correct

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan would you mind editing your answer. I am not sure I understand.

Comment: Try the same pattern as your others. But instead of the label put an input type text. Not too sure if that will wrap un-nicely or the width of the text input may be unsavory. Bootstrap does have some "before" css classes for such cases. Forget what they are called off hand but they are in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My example:  [codeply](https://www.codeply.com/p/LdtH9snMWD)

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


What is your favorite color?
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="id1">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="id1">Red</label>
</div>
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="id2">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="id2">Green</label>
</div>
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="id3">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="id3">Blue</label>
</div>
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="id4">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="id4">Other</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Custom Color Choice">
</div>
```

Expanding on that with a bit of jquery to automatically tick the checkbox with a value in the text input:

```js
$("#myTextBox").on("keyup", function() {
    if ($("#myTextBox").val().length === 0) {
        $('#id4').prop('checked', false);
    } else {
        $('#id4').prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

What is your favorite color?
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="id1">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="id1">Red</label>
</div>
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="id2">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="id2">Green</label>
</div>
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="id3">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="id3">Blue</label>
</div>
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="id4">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="id4">Other</label>
  <input id="myTextBox" type="text" placeholder="Custom Color Choice">
</div>
```

Comment: Good work!! Would it be possible to remove the label? And also to make it so that when typed in, it automatically checks the box and when empty it unchecks it? Thanks!!!

Comment: @JJT your automatic checks question is technically unrelated to your original question.

Comment: @GetSet sorry, I should have added it. I was implying that functionality (or at least something like it), but realize now that it is not clear.

Comment: for the automatic you will need javascript or jquery.  What do you mean by label?  the word "other"?  of course you can remove it

Comment: Only meant if debugging issues arose on the new question, it would be suited better in a new thread with different title.

Comment: something like this? [https://www.codeply.com/p/pt35efYsKt](https://www.codeply.com/p/pt35efYsKt)

Comment: or maybe this: [https://www.codeply.com/p/lJyn9zJaRG](https://www.codeply.com/p/lJyn9zJaRG)

Comment: @JJT or this for auto tick of checkbox: [https://www.codeply.com/p/KFHEgOvOoQ](https://www.codeply.com/p/KFHEgOvOoQ)

Comment: for better functionality, use `prop` instead of `attr`.  Then the function works even if the user checks the box first then types and deletes.  With `attr`, the function stops as soon as user checks the box.

Answer (score 0):

You could manipulate the `display` state of a `type="text"` using CSS and the Adjacent sibling combinator `~`

```css
.revealTextInput input[type="text"] {
  display: none;
}
.revealTextInput input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ input[type="text"]{
  display: initial;
}
.revealTextInput input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
What is your favorite color?

<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="id1">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="id1">Red</label>
</div>
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="id2">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="id2">Green</label>
</div>
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="id3">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="id3">Blue</label>
</div>
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox revealTextInput">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="id4">
  <input type="text" class="custom-control-input" placeholder="Enter your favorite Color">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="id4">Other...</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer! I am more looking for an input field to the right of a checkbox. Does this make sense?

Comment: @JJT Added an example

Comment: Looks great!! Is there any way to show the other field the whole time? I just meant for it to have a placeholder of "other"?

Comment: @JJT sure, just remove from CSS the  last block. - Play around.